# Запятая после значит

Tags: пунктуация

В афоризме "Не замечать охлаждения людей — значит, мало ценить их дружбу" нужна запятая после значит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цитата из ПАС Лопатина:

§ 96. Многие из вводных слов и сочетаний слов могут быть омонимичны членам предложения или союзам. Такие различия (они отражаются на пунктуации) проявляются в контексте.

...*Понять человека — значит простить (значит — связка в сказуемом).*

**В вашем предложении запятая после слова ЗНАЧИТ не нужна, так как вводным словом оно в данном случае не является. ЗНАЧИТ здесь выполняет функцию связки в сказуемом.**